# Proof's involving Zorn's Lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

my assignment is to prove a theorem using Zorn's Lemma.

What are some good theorems that Zorn's Lemma is applicable to (on the easy/moderate level).

Comment: "good theorem" vs. "bad theorem" ?

Comment: Maybe you could include Zorn's lemma in the question to give it some substance, save potential question askers time to look it up, ensure you know it also ;) ? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Two standard results are that every ring has a maximal ideal, and that each vector space has a basis. Those are probably under the "easy" category.

A more difficult problem would be to prove the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Every *non-zero* ring.

Comment: @Xam Some times I am of the opinion that rings must have $1\neq0$.

Comment: @Arthur : I think Xam's comment was there to clarify for those who aren't of the same opinion ;) and since both conventions exist, I think it's necessary to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Useful in topology:

Every filter on a set is contained in an ultrafilter.

Every net has a universal subnet.

Answer (score 1):

For any two sets $A$, $B$, either there is an injection $A\to B$, or there is one $B\to A$

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @max_zorn : It's quite easy actually : let $\Omega$ be the set of pairs $(F, f)$ where $F\subset A, f: F\to B$ is an injection ordered by $(F,f) \leq (G,g)$ iff $F\subset G$ and $f\subset g$. Then $\Omega$ is inductive, and so has a maximal element. Then you look at whether this maximal element is of the form $(A,f)$ or not and thus tells you which way you have an injection.

Comment: Thanks - very nice! This is something that undergraduates can be taught, super!

Answer (score 0):

You should prove that every finitely generated (non-trivial) group has a maximal subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one: Let $F$ be a field, $L_1, L_2$ algebraic extensions of $F$ with $L_2$ algebraically closed. Then any homorphism  $\sigma: F\rightarrow L_2$ has an extension  $\tau:L_1\rightarrow L_2$ such that the restriction of $\tau$ on $F$ is $\sigma$.